# Jest promise not resolving

Tags: express, asynchronous, testing, jestjs, supertest

I am testing my express server in Jest. All test pass but Jest doesn't close or exit. I have no idea why but I believe my server is closing after the test runs. I tried running yarn jest --detectOpenHandles and the response came back saying "Jest has detected the following 1 open handle potentially keeping Jest from exiting:

- Promise"

Here is my code...

```
const request = require('supertest');
const app = require('../server');


const server = app.listen(8000, '127.0.0.1');

afterAll(() => {
  server.close();
});

describe('GET /', () => {
  it('should respond with JSON (list of all users)', async () => {
    try {
      const response = await request(server).get('/')
        .expect('Content-Type', /json/);
      expect(response.statusCode).toBe(200);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  });
});
```

I can't seem to understand why the promise isn't resolving if that's actually the issue. My express app is pulling data from Firebase and returning the data once a get request is made. Any ideas on what's going on?

In Server.js file I connect to Firebase maybe this is the issue?

```
const db = admin.database();
const ref = db.ref('users');

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
// Attach an asynchronous callback to read the data at our posts reference
  ref.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    res.send(parseUsers(snapshot.val()));
    res.status(200);
  }, function (errorObject) {
    res.send([],'The read failed: ' + errorObject.code);
    res.status(500);
  });
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually jest throws that message when you are not handling properly a promise. Take a look yo your firebase connection methods, maybe you need to await to some promise to resolve or not returned value properly.

the ref and db const are you sure you don't need to await to them?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34759475)